# TCP, UDP, and serial communications using a single Node.js server

Tags: node.js, tcp, serial-port, udp

We're developing a controller for a test fixture that needs to communicate via a serial port and UDP. My plan was to use [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) to provide the I/O communications hub as shown in the figure below. The Node.js I/O hub would need communicate using the following:

- **UDP**: Two UDP datagrams are received every 50 ms and two UDP datagrams are sent every 50 ms.
- **Serial Port:** A serial port connection would be used to read and update values from the test fixture.
- **TCP:** An [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org) web-based user interface that communicates via a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API to the Node.js server to:

  1. Read and update the test fixture values received/sent via the serial port and UDP datagrams.
  2. Request test results be saved to a MongoDB instance.
- **MongoDB:** Provide persistent storage for test records.

### Questions

1. Can I use [Express](http://expressjs.com) and communicate via UDP and the serial port with Node.js?
2. Is this a reasonable architecture for communicating via the serial port, UDP, and TCP, especially in light of the requirements to send two UDP datagrams every 50 ms? I'm open to architecture recommendations.

[image: Node Server Communications]

Comment: You'd use express for the web portion, but the UDP portions using the network library, and the serial port stuff with a 3rd party library like `node-serialport` or similar.

Comment: @Joe You're not aware of any constraints of using Express, the UDP network library, and `node-serialport` in the same Node server? Any concerns with the requirement to send and receive UDP datagrams every 50 ms?